# Memory leak at simple loading/saving of files

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

As part of my thesis, I need to load, modify and save .dds texture files. Therefore I'm using the DevIL.NET-Wrapper library (but the problem isn't specific to this library I guess, it's more of a general problem).

I managed (by using the visual studio memory analysis tools) to figure out the memory leaking function inside the DevIL.NET-Wrapper:

```
public static byte[] ReadStreamFully(Stream stream, int initialLength) {
        if(initialLength < 1) {
            initialLength = 32768; //Init to 32K if not a valid initial length
        }

        byte[] buffer = new byte[initialLength];
        int position = 0;
        int chunk;

        while((chunk = stream.Read(buffer, position, buffer.Length - position)) > 0) {
            position += chunk;

            //If we reached the end of the buffer check to see if there's more info
            if(position == buffer.Length) {
                int nextByte = stream.ReadByte();

                //If -1 we reached the end of the stream
                if(nextByte == -1) {
                    return buffer;
                }

                //Not at the end, need to resize the buffer
                byte[] newBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length * 2];
                Array.Copy(buffer, newBuffer, buffer.Length);
                newBuffer[position] = (byte) nextByte;
                buffer = newBuffer;
                position++;
            }
        }

        //Trim the buffer before returning
        byte[] toReturn = new byte[position];
        Array.Copy(buffer, toReturn, position);

        return toReturn;
    }
```

I did a test program to figure out where the memory leak actually comes from:

```
private static void testMemoryOverflow(string[] args)
    {
        DevIL.ImageImporter im;
        DevIL.ImageExporter ie;

        ...

        foreach (String file in ddsPaths)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open))
            {
                /* v  memory leak  v */

                DevIL.Image img = im.LoadImageFromStream(fs);

                /* ^  memory leak  ^ */

                ie.SaveImage(img, fileSavePath);
                img = null;
            }

        }

    }
```

The LoadImageFromStream() function is also part of the DevIL.NET-Wrapper, and in fact calling the function from above. This is where the leak occurs.

What I already tried:

- Using GC.Collect()
- Disposing the FileStream object manually instead of using the using{} directive
- Disposing the stream inside the DevIL.NET ReadStreamFully() function from above

Does anyone have a solution for this? 
I'm new to C#, so maybe it's kind of a basic mistake.

Comment: Have you tried closing your file handles when you're done with them via fs.Close()?

Comment: Yes I did, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I assume you are using System.Drawing.Image in this line - Image img = im.LoadImageFromStream(fs); which inherits IDisposable. Try wrapping it within a using clause.

Comment: Thank you, but in fact it is not System.Drawing.Image :( 
I modified the code above, so that it's not so confusing any longer.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is the buffer size.

```
byte[] newBuffer = new byte[buffer.Length * 2];
```

After 2 iterations.. you're already very close to the 85K limit of objects hitting the Large Object Heap. At 3 iterations.. you've hit the threshold. Once there.. they won't be collected until a full garbage collection occurs across all generations. Even then.. the LOH isn't compacted.. so you'll still see some high memory.

I'm not sure why the library you're using does this. I'm not sure why you're using it either.. given that you can use:

```
Image img = Image.FromStream(fs); // built into .NET.
```

The way that library is written looks like it was from an earlier version of .NET. It doesn't appear to have memory usage as any sort of concern.

Comment: Thanks for your response. :)

I'm using this library because I need to load and modify .dds texture files, which isn't supported by native c#. 
The Image object in my test program isn't a System.Drawing.Image but a DevIL.Image, sorry for the confusion.

So if the buffer size is the problem I definitly need to modify the function of the library. On a first look, do you know how I could modify the function so it does not allocate too much memory?

Comment: While thinking about that, I came up with this:
Since the process is "load file -> modify file -> save file", as soon as I saved the modified file, is there no possibilty to somehow just clear the buffer and releasing it's allocated memory?

Comment: No there isn't. Since the buffer is on the Large Object Heap.. that heap is now expanded and managed by the CLR. Ideally you would just allocate a smaller buffer and re-use it in every iteration of a loop like that. Since the LOH is that size.. collection of the memory inside it now just means that the CLR will re-use that area that is now empty. The actual size of the LOH is still as it was.